# Difficulty using LAG to get monthly progress percentage

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, mysql-5.7

I have the following table below and would like to take the monthly evolution (%) of total transactions per month. I researched the *LAG* function but could not understand very well.

I need the return of this query to be like this (Desired Output):

```
MONTH | TOTAL TRANSACTIONS  | % EVOLUTION
----------------------------------------
09    | 45.561              | 0%
10    | 48.598              | 6.66%
```

**UPDATE**

> % EVOLUTION = ((current value - previous value) / previous value) *
>   100

It is the formula I use to calculate the evolution of the number of transactions from one month to the previous month.
That is, a column with the previous month's total is required.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campanha` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ano_mes` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `conta` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `valor` float(10,2) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `transacoes` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

can anybody help me?

MySQL Version: 5.7.23 - MySQL Community Server

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73f38f/2

Comment: someone please?

Comment: The LAG function is not supported by your Mysql version. Post sample data and the expected output of that data to clarify.

Comment: You provided sample structure and what you want, but would also help to edit original post and show some sample data that shows the accumulation of evolution and total transactions. What is the basis of your % evolution.  Please clarify that during your edit too.

Comment: Okay, that detail really missed, sorry. Post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 5.x does not support window functions such as `LAG`. You'll have to do it the old way. Based on table structure the following query should get you started:

```sql
SELECT yyyy
     , mm
     , txn_this_month
     , (txn_this_month - (
           SELECT SUM(transacoes)
           FROM campanha
           WHERE ano_mes >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', yyyy, mm, 1),'%Y-%c-%e') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
           AND   ano_mes <  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', yyyy, mm, 1),'%Y-%c-%e')
       )) / txn_this_month * 100 AS perc_change
FROM (
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ano_mes) AS yyyy
         , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ano_mes) AS mm
         , SUM(transacoes) AS txn_this_month
    FROM campanha
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ano_mes), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ano_mes)
) AS x
ORDER BY yyyy, mm
```

The subquery inside select calculates sum for previous month for each row.

Comment: I'm going to test tomorrow morning at my work. Just get access to the database from there.

Comment: I tested it here and it worked correctly. It was exactly what I wanted. Thank you